# How do I get a thread safe print in Python 2.6?

Tags: python, multithreading

`print` in Python is not thread safe according to [these](http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/70606.html) [articles](http://bramcohen.livejournal.com/70686.html).

A Python 3 work-around is offered in the latter article.

How do I get a thread safe `print` in Python 2.6?

Comment: Those articles are about Python 3. Where are the articles stating that `print` in Python 2.x is not thread-safe?

Comment: Ignacio: I've seen it myself :-)  Try spinning up a few threads all printing to stdout. The lines will be all messed up.

Comment: The second article https://bramcohen.livejournal.com/70686.html seems to just use a Lock, there isn't anything Python 3 specific about it I think.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Interesting problem -- considering all the things that happen within a `print` statement, including the setting and checking of the `softspace` attribute, making it "threadsafe" (meaning, actually: a thread that's printing only yields "control of standard output" to another thread when it's printing a newline, so that each entire line that's output is guaranteed to come from a single thread) was a bit of a challenge (the usual easy approach to **actual** thread safety -- delegating a separate thread to exclusively "own" and handle `sys.stdout`, communicate to it via Queue.Queue -- isn't all that useful, since the problem is **not** thread safety [[even with a plain `print` there is no risk of crashing and the characters that end up on standard output are exactly those which get printed]] but the need for mutual exclusion among threads for an extended range of operations).

So, I think I made it...:

```
import random
import sys
import thread
import threading
import time

def wait():
  time.sleep(random.random())
  return 'W'

def targ():
  for n in range(8):
    wait()
    print 'Thr', wait(), thread.get_ident(), wait(), 'at', wait(), n

tls = threading.local()

class ThreadSafeFile(object):
  def __init__(self, f):
    self.f = f
    self.lock = threading.RLock()
    self.nesting = 0

  def _getlock(self):
    self.lock.acquire()
    self.nesting += 1

  def _droplock(self):
    nesting = self.nesting
    self.nesting = 0
    for i in range(nesting):
      self.lock.release()

  def __getattr__(self, name):
    if name == 'softspace':
      return tls.softspace
    else:
      raise AttributeError(name)

  def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    if name == 'softspace':
      tls.softspace = value
    else:
      return object.__setattr__(self, name, value)

  def write(self, data):
    self._getlock()
    self.f.write(data)
    if data == '\n':
      self._droplock()

# comment the following statement out to get guaranteed chaos;-)
sys.stdout = ThreadSafeFile(sys.stdout)

thrs = []
for i in range(8):
  thrs.append(threading.Thread(target=targ))
print 'Starting'
for t in thrs:
  t.start()
for t in thrs:
  t.join()
print 'Done'
```

The calls to `wait` are intended to *guarantee* chaotically mixed output in the absence of this mutual exclusion guarantee (whence the comment).  *With* the wrapping, i.e., the above code exactly as it looks there, and (at least) Python 2.5 and up (I believe this may run in earlier versions, too, but I don't have any easily at hand to check) the output is:

```
Thr W -1340583936 W at W 0
Thr W -1340051456 W at W 0
Thr W -1338986496 W at W 0
Thr W -1341116416 W at W 0
Thr W -1337921536 W at W 0
Thr W -1341648896 W at W 0
Thr W -1338454016 W at W 0
Thr W -1339518976 W at W 0
Thr W -1340583936 W at W 1
Thr W -1340051456 W at W 1
Thr W -1338986496 W at W 1
  ...more of the same...
```

The "serialization" efect (whereby the threads appear to "nicely round-robin" as above) is a side effect of the fact that the thread that gets to be the currently-printing one is seriously slower than the others (all those waits!-).  Commenting out the `time.sleep` in `wait`, the output is instead

```
Thr W -1341648896 W at W 0
Thr W -1341116416 W at W 0
Thr W -1341648896 W at W 1
Thr W -1340583936 W at W 0
Thr W -1340051456 W at W 0
Thr W -1341116416 W at W 1
Thr W -1341116416 W at W 2
Thr W -1338986496 W at W 0
  ...more of the same...
```

i.e. a more typical "multithreaded output"... except for the guarantee that each line in the output comes entirely from one single thread.

Of course, a thread that does, e.g., `print 'ciao',` *will* keep "ownership" of standard output until it finally does perform a print without a trailing comma, and other threads wanting to print may sleep for quite a while (how else can one guarantee that each line in the output comes from a single thread? well, one architecture would be to accumulate partial lines to thread local storage instead of actually  writing them to standard output, and only do the writing on receipt of the `\n`... delicate to interleave properly with `softspace` settings, I fear, but probably feasible).

Answer (score 27):

Through experimentation, I found that the following works, is simple, and suits my needs:

```
print "your string here\n",
```

Or, wrapped in a function,

```
def safe_print(content):
    print "{0}\n".format(content),
```

My understanding is that the implicit newline of a normal `print` is actually output to stdout in a separate operation, causing the race condition with other `print` operations. By removing this implicit newline with the added `,`, and instead including the newline in the string, we can avoid this problem.

---

**2020 Edit:** Here's the Python 3 version of this (thanks to Bob Stein in the comments for the inspiration):

```py
def safe_print(*args, sep=" ", end="", **kwargs):
    joined_string = sep.join([ str(arg) for arg in args ])
    print(joined_string  + "\n", sep=sep, end=end, **kwargs)
```

As pointed out by Bob Stein, relying on `print` to join multiple passed arguments results in garbled output, so we have to do it ourselves.

---

**2017 Edit:** this answer is starting to pick up some steam, so I just wanted to make a clarification. This doesn't actually make `print` "thread safe" exactly. The output may be in the wrong order if the `print`s happen microseconds apart from each other. What this *does* do, however, is avoid garbled output coming from `print` statements executed from concurrent threads, which is what most people really want when asking this question.

Here is a test to show what I mean:

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor


def normal_print(content):
    print content

def safe_print(content):
    print "{0}\n".format(content),


with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    print "Normal Print:"
    for i in range(10):
        executor.submit(normal_print, i)

print "---"

with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
    print "Safe Print:"
    for i in range(10):
        executor.submit(safe_print, i)
```

Output:

```
Normal Print:
0
1
23

4
65

7
 9
8
----
Safe Print:
1
0
3
2
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: If you send your python script to the background by putting an & at the end of the command line in bash, and then exit your bash shell, the thread will crash when it hits this specially crafted print statement with "IOError: [Errno 5] Input/output error". You must redirect standard output somewhere before sending to a background job and then logging off. I'm using Python 2.7.12, by the way.

Comment: By the way, if I do a normal print and send the program to the background and logoff, I get the problem this guy is describing when the python script completes and the interpreter is shutting down (not when the print statement occurs). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790328/how-to-silence-sys-excepthook-is-missing-error So, there is something different in how the standard output is being processed with the implicit and explicit newline.

Comment: `print("One string with no commas and its own LF\n", end="")` is the Python 3 version. For me it seemed those **two criteria** made print() atomic. But `print("Separate", "strings", "joined by commas\n", end="")` was vulnerable to being hacked apart.

Comment: @BobStein Updated with Python 3 version

Answer (score 23):

The issue is that python uses seperate opcodes for the NEWLINE printing and the printing of the object itself.  The easiest solution is probably to just use an explicit sys.stdout.write with an explicit newline.

Comment: From my recent experience, this is absolutely true. I'm not exactly sure why it happens, but the `print` statement (even when STDOUT is properly serialized and flushed) will output erratic newlines. You *must* use `sys.stdout.write(s + '\n')` to avoid this.

Comment: Just using sys.stdout.write is no guarantee of serialized output in a multithreaded environment. You also need a Lock.

Answer (score 13):

I dont know if there is any better way instead this locking mechanism, but atleast it looks easy. I am also not sure if printing really isnt thread safe.

Edit: Okay tested it my self now, you are right, you can get really wierd looking output. And you dont need the **future** import, its just there, because i use Python 2.7.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from threading import Lock

print_lock = Lock()
def save_print(*args, **kwargs):
  with print_lock:
    print (*args, **kwargs)

save_print("test", "omg", sep='lol')
```

Comment: @evilpie: I reckon you are using python3 after all. Eg. in python 2.7 - `print ("test1", "test2")` is actually executed as `print tuple("test1", "test2")`. Therefore the `*args, **kwargs` parameters are not correct and are not the same as `print "test1", "test2"`.