# python 2.7.5 print one more '\n'

Tags: python, multithreading

cat t.py

```
import threading
import sys

class RecoverKey(threading.Thread):
    cond = threading.Condition()
    def __init__(self, idx=0):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.idx = idx
    def run(self):
        for i in range(5):
            self.cond.acquire()
            print(self.idx * 10)
            sys.stdout.flush()
            self.idx *= 10
            self.cond.release()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1, 3):
        r = RecoverKey(i)
        r.start()

:~/test>python t.py 

10

20
100
200
1000
2000
10000
20000
100000
200000
```

Why there is one more line between '10' and '20'?

And sometime it may disappear..

Comment: i can confirm on hello.co's behalf that the issue is real

Comment: This is interesting, I changed `3` to larger value and there's always one more line.

Comment: Does it happen if you use `sys.stderr = sys.stdout`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a thread safe print in Python 2.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816/how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6)

Answer (score 0):

I would check out these [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7687862/why-a-script-that-uses-threads-prints-extra-lines-occasionally) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816/how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6), which deal with the same issue. I'm not sure why it's happening, but it looks like replacing `print x` with `print >> sys.stderr, x` works (tried it).