# Python 2.7: Print thread safe

Tags: python, thread-safety

I've seen a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816/how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6) however it refers to Python 2.6 and I was hoping there was an easier way.

From reading the thread it seems the best way is to just replace all my print statements with sys.stdout.write(s + '\n') ?

I was hoping there was a nicer way that allowed me still to use print

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
from __future__ import print_function
print = lambda x: sys.stdout.write("%s\n" % x)
```

Is a nice cheap and dirty hack.

Comment: awesome. Is there any downside to always adding this to a python file? (i.e. why not always have thread safety)

Comment: It doesn't handle [`print() keyword arguments`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print). As well as it makes output always unbuffered.

Comment: As I said. Its a cheap and dirty hack. Its not the "right" way to do it but it gets the job done.

Comment: you can add sys.stdout.flush() at the end of the lambda too

Comment: Is it documented somewhere that `sys.stdout.write` is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the following works on both multi-thread&multi-process environment, very simple:

```
def sprint(content):
    print("{0}~{1}\r".format(str(datetime.datetime.now()), content))
```