# How to prevent thread print to mix output in the console?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, logging, swift4

Say we have multiple threads issuing prints.
Typically when downloading stuffs as follows:

```
let url = self.url
print("loadPreview(\(source) for \(url)): ↝start loading \(self.url")
let task = session.downloadTask(with: url) { 
    (localUrl, response, error) in
    print("loadPreview(\(source) for \(url)): == \(self.url")
}
```

Is there any way to make print atomic and prevent output as follows?

```
loadPreview(WSJ for www.wsj.co⟷TloadPreview(9loadPreview(appleins   for appleinsid⟷n-messages):     ↝start loading http://app⟷n-messages
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python 2.7: Print thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7877850/python-2-7-print-thread-safe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick hack is just to use a [`NSLock`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nslock) around your print. For instance, you could define an *atomic print function* as:

```
private let printLock = NSLock()

func aprint(_ message: String){
    printLock.lock()
    defer { printLock.unlock() }
    print(message)
}
```

and use it like the standard `print` function:

```
aprint(“This will print atomically!”)
```

You could also achieve a similar result using a serial [`DispatchQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqueue) to *serialize* your print calls as well. For instance:

```
private let printQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "aprint", qos: .utility)

func aprint(_ message: String){
    printQueue.async {
        print(message)
    }
}
```

This solution provides better performance mainly thanks to the `async` call. This ensures the calling thread will *not* block until the lock is acquired (and the corresponding `print` is completely performed). But, to be clear, this solution is also perfectly atomic as well.

(For the record, simply using `DispatchQueue.main` might behave weirdly if the calling code is *also* running on the main queue.)

I would recommend picking the second solution ;)

Comment: Will this solution differs from what I already tested?, aka: objc_sync_enter(self); print(text); objc_sync_exit(self);

Comment: Same result *if* all `print` calls use the same object as lock (i.e., the `self` var your code). Otherwise you might still see mixed outputs when printing from different objects. Anyway, I recommend you wrap the selected solution in nice API to also improve code readability;)

Comment: ...but the `DispatchQueue` based solution might provide a slightly better performance ;)

Comment: So I understand why the prints still mix, the self is not a single instance. Would you mind to modify your answer and show me how the DispatchQueue solution looks like?

Comment: Thanks @Paulo I picked the DispatchQueue solution up

Comment: Well, that's weird: on an real device, I have the same results than before: I tried the two methods: 2-loadPreview(Mac4eve2-loadPreview(i1-loadPreview(cnet     for www.cnet.c⟷CAD590a51e :  ↝start loading www.cnet.c⟷CAD590a51e
I really don"'t get it

Comment: @StéphanedeLuca Are you defining a *single* `printQueue` in your codebase? Also double check that your device deployment workflow is working as expected...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DispatchIO` to automatically serialise the output to either stdout or even a file in a non-blocking fashion. It's a bit more work and you may want to wrap the example below into a class:

```
import Foundation

// Open stdout with DispatchIO
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()
let fd = FileHandle.standardOutput.fileDescriptor
let writer = DispatchIO(type: .stream, fileDescriptor: fd, queue: queue) { (errno) in
  if errno != 0 {
    print("Cannot open stdout: \(errno)")
  }
}

// Encode string
if let data = string.data(using: .utf8) {
  data.withUnsafeBytes { (buffer) in
    // Produce DispatchData with encoded string
    let dispatchData = DispatchData(bytes: buffer)

    // Print string to stdout
    writer.write(offset: .zero, data: dispatchData, queue: queue) { (done, data, errno) in
      if errno != 0 {
        print("Write error: \(errno)")
      }
    }
  }
}

// Close the DispatchIO when you don't need it anymore
writer.close()
```