# How to silence "sys.excepthook is missing" error?

Tags: python, exception, io

NB: I have not attempted to reproduce the problem described below under Windows, or with versions of Python other than 2.7.3.

The most reliable way to elicit the problem in question is to pipe the output of the following test script through `:` (under `bash`):

```
try:
    for n in range(20):
        print n
except:
    pass
```

I.e.:

```
% python testscript.py | :
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

My question is:

> *How can I modify the test script above* to avoid the error message when the script is run as shown (under Unix/`bash`)?

(As the test script shows, the error cannot be trapped with a `try-except`.)

The example above is, admittedly, highly artificial, but I'm running into the same problem *sometimes* when the output of a script of mine is piped through some 3rd party software.

The error message is certainly harmless, but it is disconcerting to end-users, so I would like to silence it.

EDIT: The following script, which differs from the original one above only in that it redefines sys.excepthook, behaves exactly like the one given above.

```
import sys
STDERR = sys.stderr
def excepthook(*args):
    print >> STDERR, 'caught'
    print >> STDERR, args

sys.excepthook = excepthook

try:
    for n in range(20):
        print n
except:
    pass
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

> How can I modify the test script above to avoid the error message when the script is run as shown (under Unix/`bash`)?

You will need to prevent the script from writing anything to standard output. That means removing any `print` statements and any use of `sys.stdout.write`, as well as any code that calls those.

The reason this is happening is that you're piping a nonzero amount of output from your Python script to something which never reads from standard input. This is not unique to the `:` command; you can get the same result by piping to any command which doesn't read standard input, such as

```
python testscript.py | cd .
```

Or for a simpler example, consider a script `printer.py` containing nothing more than

```
print 'abcde'
```

Then

```
python printer.py | python printer.py
```

will produce the same error.

When you pipe the output of one program into another, the output produced by the writing program gets backed up in a buffer, and waits for the reading program to request that data from the buffer. As long as the buffer is nonempty, any attempt to close the writing file object is supposed to fail with an error. This is the root cause of the messages you're seeing.

The specific code that triggers the error is in the C language implementation of Python, which explains why you can't catch it with a `try`/`except` block: it runs after the contents of your script has finished processing. Basically, while Python is shutting itself down, it attempts to close `stdout`, but that fails because there is still buffered output waiting to be read. So Python tries to report this error as it would normally, but `sys.excepthook` has already been removed as part of the finalization procedure, so that fails. Python then tries to print a message to `sys.stderr`, but that has already been deallocated so again, it fails. The reason you see the messages on the screen is that the Python code does contain a contingency `fprintf` to write out some output to the file pointer directly, even if Python's output object doesn't exist.

## Technical details

For those interested in the details of this procedure, let's take a look at the Python interpreter's shutdown sequence, which is implemented in the [`Py_Finalize` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L404) of `pythonrun.c`.

1. After invoking exit hooks and shutting down threads, the finalization code calls [`PyImport_Cleanup`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/import.c#L428) to finalize and deallocate all imported modules. The next-to-last task performed by this function is [removing the `sys` module](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/import.c#L536), which mainly consists of calling [`_PyModule_Clear`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/moduleobject.c#L100) to clear all the entries in the module's dictionary - including, in particular, the standard stream objects (the Python objects) such as `stdout` and `stderr`.
2. When a value is removed from a dictionary or replaced by a new value, [its reference count is decremented](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/dictobject.c#L519) using [the `Py_DECREF` macro](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Include/object.h#L771). Objects whose reference count reaches zero become eligible for deallocation. Since the `sys` module holds the last remaining references to the standard stream objects, when those references are unset by `_PyModule_Clear`, they are then ready to be deallocated.<sup>1</sup>
3. Deallocation of a Python file object is accomplished by [the `file_dealloc` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L612) in `fileobject.c`. This first [invokes the Python file object's `close` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L456) using the aptly-named [`close_the_file` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L421):

   ```
   ret = close_the_file(f);
   ```

   For a standard file object, `close_the_file(f)` [delegates to the C `fclose` function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/fileobject.c#L496), which sets an error condition if there is still data to be written to the file pointer. `file_dealloc` then checks for that error condition and prints the first message you see:

   ```
   if (!ret) {
       PySys_WriteStderr("close failed in file object destructor:\n");
       PyErr_Print();
   }
   else {
       Py_DECREF(ret);
   }
   ```
4. After printing that message, Python then attempts to display the exception using [`PyErr_Print`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L1062). That delegates to [`PyErr_PrintEx`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L1156), and as part of its functionality, `PyErr_PrintEx` attempts to access the Python exception printer from `sys.excepthook`.

   ```
   hook = PySys_GetObject("excepthook");
   ```

   This would be fine if done in the normal course of a Python program, but in this situation, `sys.excepthook` has already been cleared.<sup>2</sup> Python checks for this error condition and prints the second message as a notification.

   ```
   if (hook && hook != Py_None) {
       ...
   } else {
       PySys_WriteStderr("sys.excepthook is missing\n");
       PyErr_Display(exception, v, tb);
   }
   ```
5. After notifying us about the missing `excepthook`, Python then falls back to printing the exception info using [`PyErr_Display`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L1221), which is the default method for displaying a stack trace. The very first thing this function does is try to access `sys.stderr`.

   ```
   PyObject *f = PySys_GetObject("stderr");
   ```

   In this case, that doesn't work because `sys.stderr` has already been cleared and is inaccessible.<sup>3</sup> So the code invokes `fprintf` directly to send the third message to the C standard error stream.

   ```
   if (f == NULL || f == Py_None)
       fprintf(stderr, "lost sys.stderr\n");
   ```

Interestingly, the behavior is a little different in Python 3.4+ because the finalization procedure now [explicitly flushes the standard output and error streams](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.4/Python/pythonrun.c#L590) before builtin modules are cleared. This way, if you have data waiting to be written, you get an error that explicitly signals that condition, rather than an "accidental" failure in the normal finalization procedure. Also, if you run

```
python printer.py | python printer.py
```

using Python 3.4 (after putting parentheses on the `print` statement of course), you don't get any error at all. I suppose the second invocation of Python may be consuming standard input for some reason, but that's a whole separate issue.

---

<sup>1</sup>Actually, that's a lie. Python's import mechanism [caches a copy of each imported module's dictionary](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/import.c#L568), which is not released until [`_PyImport_Fini`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/import.c#L270) runs, [later in the implementation of `Py_Finalize`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/pythonrun.c#L480), and *that's* when the last references to the standard stream objects disappear. Once the reference count reaches zero, `Py_DECREF` deallocates the objects *immediately*. But all that matters for the main answer is that the references are removed from the `sys` module's dictionary and then deallocated sometime later.

<sup>2</sup>Again, this is because the `sys` module's dictionary is cleared completely before anything is really deallocated, thanks to the attribute caching mechanism. You can run Python with the `-vv` option to see all the module's attributes being unset before you get the error message about closing the file pointer.

<sup>3</sup>This particular piece of behavior is the only part that doesn't make sense unless you know about the attribute caching mechanism mentioned in previous footnotes.

Comment: A very lucid and concise explanation of something that would normally have me grasping for an oxygen tank (drowning. need. more. air!), thanks!

Comment: In the case that the output of the python script is needed by other programs, e.g. grep, is there any better way to implement than `python printer.py | grep "abc"`?

Comment: @MarkZ. honestly the best solution is not to pipe the output of the Python script to a program which doesn't read it - i.e. avoid the entire situation which caused this question to come up in the first place. If that's not possible for some strange reason, you could implement a command-line option like `--quiet` or `--silent` which will suppress all output from the Python script.

Comment: Honestly, how are people supposed to avoid this error when doing `generateOutput.py | less` and quitting `less` on the first screenful?  Not writing to `sys.stdout` (or not writing output entirely) is not much of workaround.  That's about as useful as "You can avoid this error by not writing code in Python."

Comment: And really, this is something that ought to be fixed in the Python interpreter itself: http://bugs.python.org/issue11380

Comment: @jamesdlin (2 comments up) I don't get this error with `less`. Perhaps `less` reads everything on standard input, or something like that, to prevent buffering errors. In any case, as I mentioned above, the _real_ solution IMO is not to pipe the output into something that doesn't consume its input. But since the question asks how to do exactly that, not writing anything to standard output is the best solution within the given constraints.

Comment: @DavidZ the most obvious place in which this comes up is if output is pipped to head, a very common use-case if you wish to check the output before redirecting to a file.

Comment: Anoter possibly bad way to silence the error: `sys.stderr.close(); sys.stdout.close()` at the very end of your script

Comment: Can emptying the buffer solve this? `import sys;
sys.stdout.flush()`

Comment: empty the buffer by flush doesn't work. But actively close the stdout and stderr in the very end of the python script file works fine.

Answer (score 11):

I ran into this sort of issue myself today and went looking for an answer.  I think a simple workaround here is to ensure you flush stdio first, so python blocks instead of failing during script shutdown.  For example:

```
--- a/testscript.py
+++ b/testscript.py
@@ -9,5 +9,6 @@ sys.excepthook = excepthook
 try:
     for n in range(20):
         print n
+    sys.stdout.flush()
 except:
     pass
```

Then with this script nothing happens, as the exception (IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe) is suppressed by the try...except.

```
$ python testscript.py  | :
$
```

Answer (score 3):

In your program throws an exception that can not be caught using try/except block. To catch him, override function `sys.excepthook`:

```
import sys
sys.excepthook = lambda *args: None
```

From [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sys.html#sys.excepthook):

> **sys.excepthook(type, value, traceback)**
>
> When an exception is raised and uncaught, the interpreter calls
>   sys.excepthook with three arguments, the exception class, exception
>   instance, and a traceback object. In an interactive session this
>   happens just before control is returned to the prompt; in a Python
>   program this happens just before the program exits. The handling of
>   such top-level exceptions can be customized by assigning another
>   three-argument function to sys.excepthook.

Illustrative example:

```
import sys
import logging

def log_uncaught_exceptions(exception_type, exception, tb):

    logging.critical(''.join(traceback.format_tb(tb)))
    logging.critical('{0}: {1}'.format(exception_type, exception))

sys.excepthook = log_uncaught_exceptions
```

Comment: Did you ***try*** this solution with the test script I provided? After all, that was the reason I provided it...

Answer (score -6):

I realize that this is an old question, but I found it in a Google search for the error.  In my case it was a coding error.  One of my last statements was:

```
print "Good Bye"
```

The solution was simply fixing the syntax to:

```
print ("Good Bye")
```

[Raspberry Pi Zero, Python 2.7.9]

Comment: In Python 2.7.9, there is no difference between having parentheses in `print` and not.