# sys.stderr lost executing odoo YML test

Tags: testing, exception, odoo, yaml

I receive this error in the logs during a yml test run:

```
close failed in file object destructor:
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr
```

I think some exception might be not properly handled.

Comment: Without a lot more detail about your code I can't tell you for sure, but: this happens when Python is cleaning up objects that were still alive at interpreter shutdown, and some file object doesn't close properly, and this happens *after* `sys.stderr` has already been closed so there's nowhere to report the error. (It ought to be impossible for `close` methods to fail, but sadly, it is not so.) To avoid this you need to make sure all files opened by your test are closed *before* interpreter shutdown; the easiest way to do that is with `with` statements.

Comment: It seems that the sys.stderr is not available in the context where odoo run the YAML tests. Note that yaml are not python files, they can have python code in the !python tag. That code is used through python "eval" function. I don't know how eval deals with the sys.stderr

Answer (score 0):

I found that happen when using print function inside a YML test.

[How to silence "sys.excepthook is missing" error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790328/how-to-silence-sys-excepthook-is-missing-error)

The proper way to log there is to use the logger:

```
import logging
_logger = logging.getLogger('TEST')
_logger.info('log message')
```