# win32security not properly installing

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to install win32security but I'm having some issues. Initially I was getting the error:

```
close failed in file object destructor:

sys.excepthook is missing

lost sys.stderr
```

So I started Command Prompt as admin and ran the .exe and it installed. However, I noticed that it couldn't install shortcuts. After importing it into Python I cannot use any functions within the module. win32security.GetFileSecurity says that no module exists. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Maybe this would help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790328/how-to-silence-sys-excepthook-is-missing-error

Comment: Well I've since fixed that issue. Apparently you need to run command prompt as Admin and run the .exe from there. So it installs, but the module itself contains empty functions. If I import win32security, it imports, but I can't use anything inside the module.