# [ERROR]: "RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stderr"

Tags: python, cpython

I'm running Python 3.7.0 and here's the code I have, it's very simple.

```
response = (input("Recipient's address: "),
        float(input("Enter the amount to send: ").replace(",", "")))
print(response)
```

When this code gets ran, the following error pops up:

`RuntimeError: input(): lost sys.stderr`

How do I fix this?

Comment: This looks somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12790328/how-to-silence-sys-excepthook-is-missing-error.  Does that help?

Comment: For me who are using Windows, your code works perfectly fine.