# How to share stdout for multi-threaded python script?

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a script which has 5 threads, i want to share/redirect stdout for all the thread, to get all prints properly.
I have tried with the below code but its not working, can anybody help?

```
class Logwriter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout

    def write(self,message):
        lock = threading.Lock()
        lock.acquire()
        self.terminal.write(message)
        lock.release()

sys.stdout=Logwriter()
```

Answer (score 11):

Instead of redirecting stdout (which won't provide redirection of stderr btw), you could also use the python [logging](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) module.

Then you can replace your print statements with logging.info("message").

The logging module provides a lot of possibilities like printing which thread posted a message etc.

Answer (score 2):

Instantiate a lock in the `__init__` method and use it with a `with` statement in the `write` method:

```
class Logwriter():
    def __init__(self):
        self.terminal = sys.stdout
        self.lock = threading.Lock()

    def write(self,message):
        with self.lock:
            self.terminal.write(message)
```

Also, this won't work because `print "hello"` calls `sys.stdout.write("hello")` first, then `sys.stdout.write("\n")`.

You'll find a similar implementation that handles that issue in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3030755/2846140) by Alex Martelli.