# How to redirect print output from multiprocessing Pool

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

How can I redirect prints that occur within a multiprocessing Pool into a `StringIO()`

I am redirecting the `sys.stdout` into a `StringIO()`, this works well as long as I don't use `pool` from the `multiprocessing` library.

This toy code is an example:

```
import io
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

print_file = io.StringIO()
sys.stdout = print_file

def a_print_func(some_string):
    print(some_string)

pool = Pool(2)  
out = pool.map(a_print_func, [['test_1','test_1'],['test_2','test_2']])

a_print_func('no_pool')
print('no_pool, no_func')

fd = open('file.txt', 'w')
fd.write(print_file.getvalue())
fd.close()
```

`file.txt` only contains:

```
no_pool
no_pool, no_func
```

instead of:

```
test_1
test_1
test_2
test_2
no_pool
no_pool, no_func
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816)

Comment: @stovfl I cant see how exactly. plus wouldn't the use of of a thread lock cancel the multiprocessing aspect ?

Comment: Since memory is not shared between the processes, the object "print_file" is not shared between the parent process and the child ones. As a result, what's written to print_file by the children is not seen by the parent.

Comment: @AnarKi  You have to use a `multiprocessing` lock instead.

Comment: If you'd like, there are ways to direct all the child process to a file.

Comment: @Roy2012 how can you get that ?

Comment: @stovfl sure, but what I mean is that you lose the parallel run aspect which is essential for me

Comment: **lose the parallel run aspect**: Yes, the core point is you hav.e to serialize your print statements. Another approach are to use a queue and a single process to read from the queue and do the print.

Comment: @AnarKi - see my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution for directing the output from all the child processes to a single file, using an initializer:

```
import io
import sys
from multiprocessing import Pool

print_file = io.StringIO()

print_file = open("file.txt", "w")

def a_print_func(some_string):
    print(some_string)

def foo(*args):
    sys.stdout = print_file

pool = Pool(2, initializer = foo)  
out = pool.map(a_print_func, [['test_1','test_1'],['test_2','test_2']])

a_print_func('no_pool')
print('no_pool, no_func')
```

The output of the program is

```
no_pool
no_pool, no_func
```

And, the content of `file.txt` at the end of the execution is:

```
['test_1', 'test_1']
['test_2', 'test_2']
```

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: this wont work if you use `print_file = io.StringIO()`. Do you know why is that and how to work around it ?

Comment: Every child process can have its own StringIO output, but they can't share it AFAIK. StingIO is in memory, and unless you find a way to share the memory StringIO is using between multiple processes, you can't do that. What you can do is have a StringIO at every child process, and print it to some file at the end of that child process.

Comment: Alternatively, the parent process can capture the child processes' stdout, and do whatever it wants with them.