# Using threading causes a mess in my terminal

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I'm trying to create a program that automatically creates accounts upon available usernames using api calls. The program works fine. However, I want it to run faster. Therefore I tried using threading but the problem is that whenever I use more than one thread my terminal creates a big mess. [youtube video on what happens](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9N4qANqwgo).

My code:

```
    # Login --> Threading --> Checker
    def login(self):
        self.headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + self.finalLogin
        r = requests.post("https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles/sessions", json={"Content-Type":"application/json"}, headers=self.headers)
        if r.status_code == 200:
            if r.json()["ticket"]:
                token = "Ubi_v1 t=" + r.json()["ticket"]
                self.headers['Authorization'] = token
                self.threading()

    def checker(self):
        [self.usernames.put(line.strip()) for line in open("external/wordlist.txt")]  
        while not self.usernames.empty():
            name = self.usernames.get(); self.usernames.put(name)
            url = f"https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?nameOnPlatform={name}&platformType=uplay"   
            try:
                r = requests.get(url, headers=self.headers)
                
                if self.checkedCount % 100 == 0:
                    self.checkedCount += 1
                    print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Message:        Using new login")
                    self.accounts()

                ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW(f"Gx | Checked: {self.checkedCount}, Available: {self.availableCount}, Errors: {self.errorCount}")
                if r.status_code == 200:
                    self.checkedCount += 1
                    if len(r.json()['profiles']) != 0:
                        print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Taken:          {name}")       
                    
                    else:  
                        print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Available:      {name}")
                        self.availableCount += 1
                        self.create(name)

                else:
                    self.errorCount += 1
                    print(f"{Fore.LIGHTBLACK_EX}[+]{Fore.RESET} Error:          Check errors.txt")
                    with open('external/errors.txt', "a") as errorFile:
                        errorFile.write(f'{self.currentTime} | Error code: {r.status_code}, Error message: {r.text}\n')
            
                    self.checkedCount += 1
                    self.accounts()

            except Exception:
                self.errorCount += 1
                pass

    def threading(self): 
        [self.usernames.put(line.strip()) for line in open("external/wordlist.txt")]   
        for x in range(5):
            threading.Thread(target=self.checker, args=()).start()
```

Comment: I have not looked at your YouTube video. However, what you have here is multiple threads *print*ing to the standard output stream concurrently. It's almost certainly going to create a "big mess".

Comment: the terminal is displaying what its supposed to, you can't call it a mess .

Answer (score 0):

What you call a mess it what happens, when using `print` while running multiple threads. This is, because `print`, especially the output buffer, is not thread safe. As described in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816/how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6), you must use a thread safe approach.

I think of two options:

1. Using a [lock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) on the print statement, e.g.

```
from threading import Lock
print_lock = Lock()

with print_lock:
    print(...)
```

2. Using a wrapper function (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029816/how-do-i-get-a-thread-safe-print-in-python-2-6)) and use that wrapper function to print things:

```
def safe_print(*args, sep=" ", end="", **kwargs):
    joined_string = sep.join([ str(arg) for arg in args ])
    print(joined_string  + "\n", sep=sep, end=end, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks, for the `safe_print` method you would have to do `safe_print('something to print')` everytime you want it to print right

Comment: That is one correct example, yes. Actually `safe_print` resembles the arguments of the real `print` function, so you should be able to use it, just as you would use `print`.

Comment: Unfortunately none of them work :/